# How to derive the calculation formula of matrix norm from its definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

Matrix norm is defined as

\begin{aligned}\|A\|&=\sup \left\{{\frac {\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}}:x\in K^{n}{\text{ with }}x\neq 0\right\}.\end{aligned}

How can we derive the following calculating formulas

\begin{aligned}\|A\|_{1}=\max _{1\leq j\leq n}\sum _{i=1}^{m}|a_{ij}|\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}\|A\|_{\infty }=\max _{1\leq i\leq m}\sum _{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned} \|A\|_{2}=\sigma _{\max }(A)\end{aligned}

Comment: What do you man by 'derive'. These formulas define different norms. They are not equal to  each other.

Comment: First two are easy: prove $\le$ and then find one that gives $=$. The last one are usually done via SVD and the unitary invariance of the 2-norm.

Comment: Yes, I know the formulas defines different norms. I want to know how to prove them respectively.

Comment: Can you give a brief provement for the first one? I have tried but not succeeded.